# Does Super Control Panel Exist for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Naming a new folder on your desktop `Super Control Panel.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C` will display all the settings in Windows 7; is there an equivalent to this for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1?

Comment: Did you try creating that folder yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is often referred to as God mode (create the following folder on your desktop):

```
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```